# s3 upload is not working by nodejs multiparty

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm trying to implement s3 upload via multiparty, but It doesn't work.

There are two problems depend on `byteCount` variable.

If I set the `ContentLenght:part.byteCount`, s3 file upload is not working.

But then, if I omit `ContentLength:part.byteCount`, s3 file upload is working. 
BUT The only part (chunk of stream?) of entire file have been uploaded. 
e.g) source file size : 100kb, uploaded file size: 20kb

My code is below. Is there any problems on my code?:

```
var form = new multiparty.Form();

form.on('field',function(name,value){    

});  

form.on('close',function(){    
  res.json({success:true});
});  

form.on('part',function(part){

  if(!part.filename) {
    part.resume();
  } 

  s3 = new AWS.S3();
  var params = {Bucket: s3bucket, Key: tempFileName, Body: part, ContentLength:part.byteCount};

  s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {                      
    console.log('s3 upload');     
  });       


  part.on('data',function(chunk){
    console.log(part.filename+' read '+chunk.length + 'bytes');
  });


  part.on('end',function(){      
    console.log(part.filename+' Part read complete');      
  }); 

}); 

form.on('progress',function(byteRead,byteExpected){
     console.log(' Reading total  '+byteRead+'/'+byteExpected);
});  

form.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log('err');
});

form.parse(req);
```

Comment: s3 emits errors when a file didn't succeed to be uploaded. Form part also emits error. Can you log them an say what is the output?
   s3.upload(params, function(err, data) {                      
    console.log(err);     
  });
  part.on('data',function(err, chunk){
    console.log(err);
  });

Comment: thank you for your answer.
but 
There are no errors.
case1. set the ContentLength:part.byteCount : 

s3.upload callback function is not called.
I think that It is waiting for end of stream.(just my opinion)

case2. omit ContentLength option. : 

On the surface There is no problem, but the size of file which is uploaded isn’t correct as I said above.

and then,

part.on('data',function(err, chunk){ console.log(err); }); 
Data listener doesn’t pass err argument to the callback. multiparty plugin could control errors in part.on(‘err’,function(err){});